# Increasing Text box value by one

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a Userform which will bring up the last value that was entered in column E.

This is good, however I would like the userform to show the last value increased by one, saving the user from having to change the value themselves.

E.g.

"MSA 00-00-0001" <-This is whats shown, as this is the last value in the column
However I would like the userform to show MSA 00-00-0002

Normally you would just use .Value + 1 I'm assuming, however this won't work due to the hyphens and the Text in the value field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you load the current value into `msa_string`, you could use:

```
newvalue="MSA " & format(1+val(replace(right(msa_string,10),"-","")),"00-00-0000")
```

If it doesn't always start `MSA_` then you could do this:

```
newvalue=left(msa_string,len(msa_string)-10) & format(1+val(replace(right(msa_string,10),"-","")),"00-00-0000")
```

Using your approach, declare msa_string as a string with your other declarations and then:

```
msa_string=Worksheets("Temp").Range("E1").End(xlDown).Value
critCode.Value = left(msa_string,len(msa_string)-10) & format(1+val(replace(right(msa_string,10),"-","")),"00-00-0000")
```

Comment: Nice , I like this idea +1

Comment: So currently this is the code that's relating to this **critCode.Value = Worksheets("Temp").Range("E1").End(xlDown).Value** Would I implement your code after this?

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can "Cheat" a little, by using the `AutoFill`.

Let's say you have `"MSA 00-00-0001"` in Cell B1, so you can use the `AutoFill` one cell down, and the value in Cell B2 will be `"MSA 00-00-0002"`. Now you can set the `TextBox1.value` to Cell B2, and afterwards just clear the contents from it.

**Code**

```
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("B1")

Rng.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Rng, Rng.Offset(1)) '<-- use AutoFill once cell down

UserForm1.TextBox1.value = Rng.Offset(1).value
Rng.Offset(1).ClearContents ' <-- clear the contents of the added cell
```

Comment: Currently the code I have in the **UserForm_Initialize** is **critCode.Value = Worksheets("Temp").Range("E1").End(xlDown).Value**, this pulls the last value, the **Temp** worksheet should ideally not be touched by the user, it should just be a means to have data pasted into, by the help of the userform